# does AutobahnJS support binary messages?

Tags: autobahn

When I send a binary message from a Python server to a JavaScript client, an exception is thrown from `JSON.parse` at [this](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnJS/blob/master/autobahn/autobahn.js#L429) codeline.  I'm sending the message like this:

```
server.sendMessageHybi(myBinaryChunk, binary=True)
```

On the receiving end, the `data` field is holding a `Blob` object rather than a string.  Wondering if this is a supported workflow, or if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send binary WebSocket messages from AutobahnPython and receive those on browser-side with pure WebSocket (you don't need AutobahnJS for that).

AutobahnJS is a *WAMP* implementation: RPC and PubSub over WebSocket. WAMPv1 uses text (JSON) messages for serialization and does not support (unencoded) binary payloads.

There are considerations for supporting binary payloads in WAMPv2 (https://github.com/tavendo/wamp/issues/4)